# how works the BAV99 circuit?

Tags: voltage, sensor, protection

I have a question about the BAV99, I use it for my voltage sensor as a protection for the ADC input but I don't really know how it works. That's why I'm turning to you, to get more information about the BAV99.

I thank you in advance for all your answers.

[image]

Comment: It's two diodes. Now you just need to know how a diode works, which is pretty basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BAV99 is simply two small signal diodes in a single package, and it is used to limit voltage to safe values so that 12V does not go into the next module like ADC or whatever.

A diode will start to conduct current when there is sufficient voltage over it. For example's sake, let's assume that it's an ideal diode and it takes about 0.7V to turn on.

If the voltage on the IC4 output goes above 3.3V + 0.7V or about 4V, the diode will start to conduct and limits the output voltage to about 4V by passing current into to 3.3V supply.

The other diode provides protection from negative voltages, but the IC4 can't output them. If it could go down to -0.7V, the other diode would start to conduct and limits the output voltage to about -0.7V by passing current to 0V supply.

Comment: This means that the maximum output voltage of this circuit is 4V ?

Comment: @Kolia Approximately 4V. It depends on how high the IC4 output goes, which determines how much current flows via the diode, and at what temperature the diode is. But yes, 4V is a reasonably good approximation. It could be 3.9V or 4.1V, but pretty close to 4V.